# Polchinski's toy model of renormalization group flow: significance of main steps

Tags: renormalization, effective-field-theory

In "[Renormalization and Effective Lagrangians](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321384902876)" (Nucl. Phys. B, 231 p269, 1984; [preprint](https://lib-extopc.kek.jp/preprints/PDF/1983/8307/8307283.pdf)), Polchinski begins section 2 with a toy model to demonstrate the renormalization group with a relevant and irrelevant coupling.

He starts with a scalar theory with a 4-point and 6-point interaction. The dimensionless couplings for these interactions are $\lambda_4$ and $\lambda_6 = \Lambda^2 g_6$ where $\Lambda$ is the scale of the theory.

The $\beta$-function equations are:
[image]

If $\bar\lambda_4, \bar\lambda_6)$ are a solution to these equations, then we can examine small deviations from this trajectory: $\varepsilon_i \equiv \lambda_i - \bar\lambda_i$.

The equations to $\mathcal O(\varepsilon)$ are:
[image]

*Now here's where I'm a bit confused*: Polchinski explains the $\lambda_6$ will term affects the relative flow of the $\lambda_4$ between nearby trajectories. For example, the following figure: two nearby points A1 and A2 have the same $\lambda_4$ but flow to points B1 and B2 which now have quite different $\lambda_4$s.

[image]

Polchinski then says that even though $\varepsilon_4$ is big, there is a point B2' on trajectory 2 that *is* close to A2. In order to illuminate this, he defines this particular combination of couplings:

[image]

**Question 1**: I don't quite see the motivation for writing this. However, Polchinski says that $(\xi_4,\xi_6)$ is a vector that points from B1 to B2', which I think I can see if I think of
$$ 
\frac{d\bar\lambda_6/d\Lambda}{d\bar\lambda_4/d\Lambda} 
=
\frac{d\bar\lambda_6}{d\bar\lambda_4} .
$$
Is that reasonable? Then I'm thinking of $\bar\lambda_6$ as a function of $bar\lambda_4$: $\bar\lambda_6 = \bar\lambda_6(\bar\lambda_4)$.

In this way, to quote Polchinski above eq (8), we are "*subtracting off a multiple of the tangent vector to the trajectory.*"

**Question 2**: I'm having a hard time showing that the flow equation for $\xi_6$ is:

[image]

Is it obvious how this follows from the earlier flow equations?

Thanks!

Comment: Permalink: https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(84)90287-6

Comment: I am trying to understand how to obtain the equations 3a and 3b from the equations before those. Do you have any idea of how that was done? I know it is just given to us in the paper but I am trying to get there from the deviation given in the paper.

Comment: @user7077252: to derive equation (3a), simply replace $\epsilon_i = \lambda_i - \bar\lambda_i$. Then use equation (2a) in the limit where $\epsilon$ is small. The finite difference between $\beta(\lambda)$ and $\beta(\bar\lambda)$ is approximately $\partial\beta/\partial\lambda$.

Comment: Where $\epsilon$ is small, meaning that $\epsilon \to 0 $. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think I've sorted it out. I share the key steps here.

For simplicity, let me write $t = \ln \Lambda$ so that $d/dt = \Lambda (d/d\Lambda)$. I further use the shorthand where $\dot\lambda = d\lambda/dt$.

**For question 1**, I believe an explanation is to annotate Polchinski's figure as follows:
[image]

Here the green line is the tangent line of the lower trajectory. The expression for the separation between the trajectories, $\xi_6$ is approximated by looking at the vertical separation between B2 and A2, $\varepsilon_6 =\lambda_6(t+\delta t)-\bar\lambda_6(t+\delta t)$, minus $\Delta \varepsilon_6$, which is the "rise" from the tangent line approximation.

**For question 2**, one can arrive at this result from simply calculating $\dot\xi_6$. It is useful to note that $\beta_i$ depends on $t$ through $\lambda_4(t)$ and $\lambda_6(t)$. This means, for example, 
$$
\dot \beta_4 = 
+ \frac{\partial \beta_4}{\partial_4}\dot\lambda_4
+ \frac{\partial \beta_4}{\partial_6}\dot\lambda_6
$$

Thus the following corollaries may be useful:

(1) $$\frac{\ddot \lambda_4}{\dot\lambda_4} = \frac{d\ln \beta_4}{dt}$$

(2) $$\ddot \lambda_6
=
2\dot\lambda_6  + \frac{\partial \beta_6}{\partial_4}\dot\lambda_4 + \frac{\partial \beta_6}{\partial_6}\dot\lambda_6
$$

(3) $$ \frac{\partial \beta_4}{\partial_6}
=
\frac{1}{\dot\lambda_6}
\left(
\dot\beta_4 
- \frac{\partial \beta_4}{\partial_\lambda 4} \dot\lambda_4
\right)
$$

Using these relations, I think it is simply a matter of applying the chain rule and grouping terms together.